# Flutter Background Processes Using Android Alarm Manager and Isolates

Tags: flutter, android-alarms, dart-isolates

I'm trying to get a timer (down to the hundredths of seconds) to work in Flutter even when the app is closed. I initially tried to use isolates as I thought they would work yet after testing with a Pixel 4 running Android 11 I found that it was still not firing correctly when the app was closed. After some googleing I came across Android Alarm Manager and I have everything set up again yet it doesn't appear that the periodic function is firing correctly.
Heres the BLoC map for triggering the counter:

```
Stream<TimerState> _mapTimerStartedToState(TimerStarted start) async* {
     AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
     port.listen((_) async => await _incrementCounter());
     startCounter();
     print(_counter);
     yield TimerRunInProgress(start.duration);
  }
```

Here's the startCounter() function:

```
void startCounter() async {
     prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     if (!prefs.containsKey(countKey)) {
       await prefs.setInt(countKey, 0);
     }
     IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      port.sendPort,
      isolateName,
     );
     await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
       Duration(milliseconds: 100),
       // Ensure we have a unique alarm ID.
       Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31)),
       callback,
       exact: true,
       wakeup: true,
     );


 }
```

And then here's my callback:

```
static Future<void> callback() async {
     print('Alarm fired!');
     // Get the previous cached count and increment it.
     final prefs = await 
     SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     int currentCount = prefs.getInt(countKey);
     await prefs.setInt(countKey, currentCount + 1);
     // This will be null if we're running in the background.
     print(currentCount);
     uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
uiSendPort?.send(null);
  }
```

Am I on the right path here? Can AndroidAlarmManager do what I'm trying to do? I'm not exactly sure why the isolate approach didn't work on its own either, the only explanation I got was that  I needed to use AndroidAlarmManager. Now, the events aren't firing at the 100 ms rate as I told them to and are instead firing 1 to several minutes apart.

Comment: you don't need to count any timers when your app is in background - you can get the current time when your app switches to foreground and update your timers

Comment: Do you have any references i could look at for this? I'm fairly new

Answer (score 0):

Android restricts the frequencies for alarms. You cannot schedule alarms as frequently as 100 milliseconds with AlarmManager.

Please refer the note in red background on : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm
> delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize
> wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications
> which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long,
> android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long,
> android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is
> earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in
> which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Comment: Ah so is there another approach I can use to create this timer or is this task not currently feasible?